# Why do birthdays show up in my calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Where can I modify if/how birthdays show up in my Google Calendar? I can't find any setting for that. Below is an example of such a birthday event that I haven't created myself. I don't have birthdays in my sidebar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You choose whether to show "Birthdays" or not from your sidebar.

[image: sidebar]

You control what to show from your settings.

Hover over `Birthdays` and choose `Settings`.
[image: Settings]

Under `Settings` you find:

[image: contacts]